# Kitchen Sink not running

Tags: android, titanium

Does anyone here had idea regarding this code. Finally emulator not running.

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.1, Titanium SDK version 3.1.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[INFO] :   Running emulator process: python "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py" "emulator" "KitchenSink" "D:\Android" "C:\Users\hp\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink" "com.appcelerator.kitchensink" "14" "WVGA854" "armeabi-v7a"
[INFO] :   Running build process:  python "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py" "simulator" "KitchenSink" "D:\Android" "C:\Users\hp\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink" "com.appcelerator.kitchensink" "14" "WVGA854"
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\hp\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink\build.log
[INFO] Building KitchenSink for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.1.0 (04/15/13 18:45 57634ef)
[INFO] :   Emulator process exited successfully
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 6s 831ms
[INFO] :   Emulator not running, exiting...
```

Comment: I don't even get as far as you. error: Emulator process exited with code 1. All other examples work. How about you?

Comment: Found the answer and posted.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to go into the Android SDK Manager and install "Android 3.0 (API 11)". Make sure the app uses emulator "Google APIs (Android 2.3.3)" and "WVGA854". I assume there's a Titanium bug because you have to install a higher API level (3.0) than is actually used (2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

Delete/Change this tag/line within Android Tag on Tiapp.xml

```
<tool-api-level>11</tool-api-level>
```

It is pointing to Api 11 (Android sdk 3.0) and if you don't use it to build the project you receive this kind of errors. Personally, I've deleted that line so that it uses the sdk set in the run configuration.